# PerformanceCounter vs Process

Tags: c#, memory, process, performancecounter

I'm trying to measure application memory usage, for the this there are two ways;

1. PerformanceCounter class (Working Set - Private)
2. Process class (PrivateMemorySize64)

But they gave to two different memory usage values.

**Questions:**

1. Why give different values​​.
2. Which one should I use.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show your code measuring this difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do they output different values​​?

Because they track different types of memory.

The **PrivateMemorySize64** property from the Process class is the equivalent of the Private Bytes performance counter.

To refresh your memory, Private bytes are memory that your application asked for (allocated), but it is not necessarily using. In addition, private bytes are not only physical memory, but also paged files etc.

On the other end the **Working Set - private** performance counter tracks a subset of the private bytes, which represents only the physical memory that a process is using and can't be shared with other processes.

> Which one should I use?

It depends on what you want to track. Both are useful (and there are even more!). If you want to track  the whole memory allocated by the running process, then Private Bytes are the way to go. If you want to track just the physical memory used by the process, then you should use Working Set.

A consistently increasing value of any of these parameters may indicate issues in your code.

Performance counters are good, and you should use them, but be aware that they include a lot of stuff not-related directly to the custom code you have written, and if you want more detailed information about your code memory utilization i would recommend complementing your analysis efforts with a good memory profiling.

Comment: What would be the difference between using a `PerformanceCounter` or the `Process` class to gather data about a certain resource the current process is using? In other words - what are the differences between the two for profiling?